# Is there a way to insert pre-written LLVM IR into a module

Tags: c++, llvm

I am working on a compiler, and my language requires that some functions are already implemented and available.

For example, if I wanted to implement a stack in my language (software) I would use the following IR:

```
@.stack = common global [1024 x i64]
@.sp = common global i64 0

define void @push(i64 %val) {
    %sp = load i64, i64* @.sp
    %addr = getelementptr [1024 x i64], [1024 x i64]* @.stack, i64 0, i64 %sp

    ; store the value
    store i64 %val, i64* %addr

    ; update the stack pointer
    %sp2 = add i64 %sp, 1
    store i64 %sp2, i64* @.sp

    ret void
}
[... other stack operations]
```

I have only found ways of doing this via creating a `llvm::Function*` but the code seemed a bit verbose for what I was trying to do.

How would I go about using the LLVM API to directly insert this code (in the form of an `std::string` or `const char*` into the start of my module (if at all possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the bitcode file with the some "library functions". Then you can load / parse this module and insert into the start of you module that uses it.

Essentially, you'd need a bitcode reading functionality and LLVM IR linker – both are standard LLVM APIs.